# php bin/magento setup:static:deploy -f won't work

Tags: magento2.4

I'm running the  `php bin/magento setup:static:deploy -f` command and it gives me this error

```
syntax error, unexpected token "match", expecting identifier#0 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#1 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#2 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Relations/Runtime.php(38): class_exists()
#3 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(157): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Relations\Runtime->has()
#4 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(180): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->_inheritInterception()
#5 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(213): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->hasPlugins()
#6 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(190): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->generateIntercepted()
#7 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Config/Config.php(122): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->initializeUncompiled()
#8 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121): Magento\Framework\Interception\Config\Config->__construct()
#9 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
#10 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()
#11 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/Environment/Developer.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()
#12 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManagerFactory.php(191): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager\Environment\Developer->configureObjectManager()
#13 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory->create()
#14 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(127): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->__construct()
#15 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(184): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create()
#16 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(84): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->initObjectManager()
#17 /var/www/magento.cm/public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
#18 {main}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your php version is compitable with your magento version .
I think your php version is php 8. it should 7.4 or compitable as per your magento version